# Why my html file loads up at bottom/footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a single page static website with only one html file. The problem I'm facing is whenever I open my html file it always opens up at the bottom/footer. I've checked the file and there is not a single `focus/autofocus` keyword used. Any one have any idea why this is happening? I have sections on my html page that I target using ids(section1, section2, section3,...). Is there any way to make the page load from top or first section?

Comment: Can you include the source code for the static page and a screen shot?

Comment: a source code sample would help to answer the question

Comment: also need to know if you use anchor in url, maybe this is the problem

Comment: I've added the link to site in question

Comment: Put a simplified code here. :)

Comment: Check the console, you have an error, maybe this cause the problem 

`catch-infinite-scroll-pro-public.js:formatted:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: selector is not defined
    at catch-infinite-scroll-pro-public.js:formatted:6`

Comment: @JesseJames we know you have added the link, but if you want to someone help you fast, you must insert your code so we can help you..thanks

Comment: It is hundreds of lines of HTML code and 35+ CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./JS/catch-infinite-scroll-pro-public.js"></script>`

this is the line causing the issue

or try doing like this

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.href = '#section0';
}
</scipt>
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue

Comment: Answer edited, Please check

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add  a JS code to move back to top, once the page loads using

```
document.getElementById("masthead").addEventListener("load", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = 'http://digitalinvo.com/#section0';
}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that would do the trick. But I've added the script and it isn't working

Comment: @JesseJames LOL buddy here replace "your_any_id" with any id from your HTML code.

Comment: @JesseJames I have updated the code.

Comment: @JesseJames please go through any code you are given before  publishing it.

Comment: try to add active class on following selector
<li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="#section0" class="active">Home</a>

Comment: @JasseJames did it solve your problem buddy??